# time based shape changing visualization

Tags: javascript, visualization, data-analysis

Imagine there are 3 kids. I have sampling of their weight for last 50 yr (for example, down to every minute) - I want to be able to play the visualization that represents their weight as the length of bar
for example: 
if kid all of their weight is 10lb each. then there will be 3 line of same length.
if kid1 gets weight to 100lb. then the length of line1 will be for example 100 and rest of the 2 lines are still at 10 (they still have same weight)

I want to be able to play back the visualization. are there any javascript library available that handles it ?

Answer (score 0):

These two libraries might work out for you

1. [impress.js](https://github.com/impress/impress.js) if you want to see a playable presentation
2. [morpheus.js](https://github.com/ded/morpheus) if you just want to custom animate on events

If your requirement varies visit [microjs.com](http://microjs.com/)